# How to use in statement with nested table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hey there I have a function, and part of the function is to make sure that the selected value is within the passed in table of varchar2s. To start I declare a varchar2 table type like so.

```
create or replace type Varchar2Table is table of varchar2(200)
```

Then I have the function which accepts the nested table parameter and has a select statement on them.

```
function SelectPeople(inputNames Varchar2Table) return People
begin
--stuff
select * from person_table where name in inputNames; --line of interest
--more stuff
end;
```

This doesn't seem to work though, I get the following error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got
>   ENGSPL5.VARCHAR2TABLE

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you receiving an error here?  If so, what?  If not, what happens?

Comment: The error is "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got ENGSPL5.VARCHAR2TABLE".

Not sure why it says expected number when I'm passing in a varchar2 on both sides though.

Comment: You're not passing VARCHAR2 on both sides though, you're asking it to convert a VARCHAR2 column to a user-defined type that it has no overload for. I think NUMBER must be its default guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TABLE` operator allows nested tables to be used in SQL statements.  The function was also missing an `IS` and an `INTO`.

```
create or replace type Varchar2Table is table of varchar2(200);

create table person_table(id number, name varchar2(100));

create or replace function SelectPeople(inputNames Varchar2Table) return number
is --Missing "IS".
    type numberTable is table of number; --Need a collection to store results.
    numbers numberTable;
begin
    select id
    bulk collect into numbers --Missing "INTO".
    from person_table
    where name in (select column_value from table(inputNames)); --Missing "TABLE".
    --Alternatively a multiset condition can be used.
    --where name member of inputNames;

    --Dummy return value to make the function compile.
    return 1;
end;
/
```

Comment: You can also use `WHERE name MEMBER OF inputNames`